# Determine if a function extends another using Resig's simple javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm using John Resig's simple [javascript inheritance code](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) to build and extend classes. I have some classes like his examples:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(isDancing){
    this.dancing = isDancing;
  },
  dance: function(){
    return this.dancing;
  }
});

var Ninja = Person.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super( false );
  },
  dance: function(){
    // Call the inherited version of dance()
    return this._super();
  },
  swingSword: function(){
    return true;
  }
});
```

I want a function that I can pass a variable and it will return true if the variable is a class that inherits from `Person`, or false if it's not.

By "inherits from `Person`" I mean that it was created by calling the `.extend()` function of Person, or of a class that inherits from `Person`.

If I have an instance of the class, I can use instanceof to determine if the class inherited from `Person`. Is there any way to do this *without creating an instance*?

Thanks!

Comment: his extend actually just copies properties, no inheritance involved. i fear your task is impossible except with static analysts or some type of expensive reflection sniffing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) with the classes' prototype:

```
function isPersonSubclass(cls) {
    return typeof cls == "function" && cls.prototype instanceof Person;
}

isPersonSubclass(Ninja) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, it looks like the prototype object is set to an instance of the parent "class":

```
// Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
// don't run the init constructor)
var prototype = new this();

// [...]

Class.prototype = prototype;
```

So you could do:

```
Ninja.prototype instanceof Person
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hCN8x/)